# Running Windows 8 from USB stick

Tags: windows-8, liveusb

For debug purposes I need to create a bootable windows 8 image on a USB drive (32 GB flash stick for preference but I could probably do a portable HD version)

Specifically our software is having problems working with Sony Vaio running Windows 8 when burning to DVD media (CD ROM media works) since the control we use seems to mis-report the media type. We have what I think is the same machine here in the office (our machine was shipped with windows 7 and thats the only difference I can see in specs) so I'd like to to see if I get the same problem in the office by running Windows 8 on that machine.

If it works in our office I can take the USB key to our client and boot their machine and see if the problem is fixed. If it's fixed then I can try removing the pre-installed software in case thats causing the problem, if it's not fixed then I've got a nasty hardware issue to try to diagnose.

I've read the windows 2 go stuff and while I could do this (we have some enterprise licences) I'm loathe to do all the faffing with image prep. (also the USB key I have here isn't Windows2Go certified)

So does anyone know if MS provide a bootable eval windows 2 go image that I can test with (I can't find one)? Or can I install windows 8 to the USB key and then boot from it via the bios without screwing up the Windows 7 install on the machine we have in the office?

Basically I'm looking for suggestions on the best way forward from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [Windows 8 90 Day Enterprise Evaluation Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx) and this lalows you to create an USB Windows To Go Drive. In the Creator select the 90 Day Enterprise Eval ISO. Now you have a USB drive that you can use for 90 days to test all your software on different systems.

Comment: Well this works sort of. There is a windows 2 go bit in the control panel which should allow this to work. However since I don't have an certified USB key it doesn't work. These instructions http://tweaks.com/windows/52279/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive/ don't work as I can't partition the USB key correctly (and gparted doesn't seem to give the right result)

Comment: I'm going to keep trying but with out the certified device (I haven't yet tried a "real" usb HD yet) I suspect it may be tricky.

Comment: you can use an old USB 2.0 2.5" HDD. This works fine.

Comment: That was my next trick to try.